# mod rewrite %2F in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/search.php?title=beatiful%2Fcat
```

I need rewrite it to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/beatiful+cat
```

I added this line in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /search.php?title=$1 [L]
```

but without success. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "but without success" - What exactly is going wrong? Can you describe the steps you took to solve it, and where you got stuck?

Comment: if I open url rewritten (http://www.mydomain.com/beatiful+cat) I get 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /search.php?title=$1 [L]
```

to your htaccess file **in your document root**, and there aren't any other rules before it, then you shouldn't be getting a 404, you should be getting a 500 internal server error because these rules will loop infinitely.

This means either your htaccess file isn't being read or you don't have `FILEINFO` override rights in whatever directory the htaccess file is in.